# How to execute sequentially two asynchronous process to get JSON with React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React + Redux.
Suppose I have A component and B component on the same screen.
Both A and B get JSON from the server by asynchronous processing.

However, I need to use the data acquired in A as a parameter for B.

Are there any events that can be run after dispatch?
Or a method in which B is executed after A is rendered.

Sorry for the abstract question.

Comment: you want to execute one after another api call?

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar Yes. it is.

Comment: i posted javascript demo code you can use logic like that can then dispatch you actions

Answer (score 0):

Check this synchronous call one after another. you can modify as per your required objective.

This is how you can call second api based on first api response.

```js
function fetchA(url){
  return fetch(url)
  .then(res=>res.json());
}
function fetchB(url, id){
  return fetch(`${url}/users/${id}`)
  .then(res=>res.json())
}

async function myFunc(url){
 let A = await fetchA(`${url}/posts/3`);
 let B = await fetchB(url, A.id);
 console.log(A)
 console.log(B)
}
myFunc('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand why you would do it like this. More information could be helpful for us to give you our opinion. Maybe you could do an example or a mocking of what you want to do?

Here is what i think could be a solution for you. Hope it helps.

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  doYourApiCall() {
    // here you do your API call normally. Here's an example of how it could happen
    //
    // fetch(`${url}/someData/`)
    //   .then(res => res.json())
    //   .then(data => {
    //     dispatch({ someData: data.someData });
    //   });
    //
    // When call ended, dispatch your data to Redux to access it in B
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.doYourApiCall();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>A</div>;
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // someData is dispatched from A api call
    if (
      this.props.someData !== null &&
      this.props.someData !== prevProps.someData
    ) {
      // make the other api call
      //
      // fetch(`${url}/otherData/${this.props.someData}`)
      //   .then(res => res.json())
      //   .then(data => {
      //     dispatch({ otherData: data.otherData });
      //   });
    }
  }

  render() {
    // this props should be taken in the redux state
    // This way, the B content get rendered only when the props otherData is available
    // Meaning that A component is mounted
    if (!this.props.otherData) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return <div>B</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <A />
        <B />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use `redux-saga`.
Now I'm trying to use it.